# GridBagLayout and FlowLayout: Components appearing at unexpected positions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout, flowlayout

**1. Question About GridBagLayout:-**
Inspite of setting **gridx=0;** for all the components, all of them are aligning in the center of the parent. **Please tell me how to fix it and please do tell me why is this unexpected behavior occuring.**

**2. Question About FlowLayout:-**

1. In the start of the example, a panel (added to the top of the parent
   panel with the GridBagLayout) is using `FlowLayout`. According to
   the documentation, in the constructor `FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,
   5, 5)`, `FlowLayout.LEFT` is for *alignment*, next two `int`'s are
   for `hgap` and `vgap`. **I am using Left alignment but still both
   the buttons appear in the center. Please tell me why?**
2. The vertical inset of all the components is much more than expected. **Why is that happening? The same value of 5 is not resulting in so much of an inset on the sides** :s

**EXAMPLE CODE:-**

```
Card(){

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel panelBtns= new JPanel();
        panelBtns.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 5));
        JButton emailBtn= new JButton("a");
        JButton saveBtn= new JButton("b");
        panelBtns.add(emailBtn);
        panelBtns.add(saveBtn);
        GridBagConstraints c= new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.insets= new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        c.weightx=1;
        c.weighty=1;
        add(panelBtns, c);

        JLabel labelTitle= new JLabel("Title");
        labelTitle.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        c= new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        c.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        c.weightx=0.35;
        c.weighty=1;
        add(labelTitle, c);

        JTextField textField= new JTextField();
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY);
        textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, 
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2)));
        c= new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.insets= new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        c.fill=c.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx= 1;
        c.weighty=1;
        add(textField,c); 

        JLabel bodyLabel= new JLabel("Detail");
        bodyLabel.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        c= new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=3;
        c.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        c.weightx=1;
        c.weighty=1;
        add(bodyLabel, c);

        JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea();
        Border border1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY);
        textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border1, 
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2)));
        c= new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=4;
        c.insets= new Insets(5, 5, 5,5);
        c.fill=c.BOTH;
        c.weightx=1;
        c.weighty=10;
        add(textArea,c);

    }
```

[image]

---

EDIT:-

I changed the values of insets but an **unwanted inset above and under the components is still there**...  It looks almost fine here because I used a small frame size for this screenshot, but when the frame is bigger, it looks ugly and misplaced.

I want the gap between `panelBtns` and `titleLabel` to be less, and that ebtween the `textFielf` and the `titleLabel` even lesser... Likewise for `bodyLabel` and `textArea`.

```
c.insets= new Insets(2,2,0,2); // panelBtns
c.insets=new Insets(0,5,0,5); //titleLabel
c.insets= new Insets(0,5,0,5); //textField
c.insets=new Insets(0,5,0,5); //bodyLabel
c.insets= new Insets(0, 5, 5,5); //textArea
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question About GridBagLayout:- Inspite of setting gridx=0; for all the
>   components, all of them are aligning in the center of the parent.
>   Please tell me how to fix it and please do tell me why is this
>   unexpected behavior occuring.

This is the default behaviour of `GridBagLayout`.  You need to use a combination of `GridBagConstrints#fill` and/or `GridBagConstrints#anchor` (and possibly `GridBagConstrints#weightx`) to change the way that components occupy the available space of the given cell

By simply adding `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;` to the `bodyLayout` and `labelTitle` constraints...

[image: Test]

> In the start of the example, a panel (added to the top of the parent
>   panel with the GridBagLayout) is using FlowLayout. According to the
>   documentation, in the constructor FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5),
>   FlowLayout.LEFT is for alignment, next two int's are for hgap and
>   vgap. I am using Left alignment but still both the buttons appear in
>   the center. Please tell me why?

This is because `GridBagLayout` is laying the `JPanel` on which the buttons reside in the center of the layout.

You can actually test and see this if you add `panelBtns.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED))`, you will see that the `panelBtns` occupies just enough space to allow the buttons to be visible (including the padding from the layout manager)

[image: Test]

Try adding `c.fill = GridBagConstaints.HORIZONTAL` to the constraints for the button panel

[image: Test]

**Updated**

> I changed the values of insets but an **unwanted inset above and under
>   the components is still there**...  It looks almost fine here because
>   I used a small frame size for this screenshot, but when the frame is
>   bigger, it looks ugly and misplaced.
>
> I want the gap between `panelBtns` and `titleLabel` to be less, and
>   that ebtween the `textFielf` and the `titleLabel` even lesser...
>   Likewise for `bodyLabel` and `textArea`.

Remove the `weighty` constraint from everything but the `JTextArea`.  You should know that `weighty/x` is a measurement from 0 to 1 which represents the percentage available space the component should take up within it's parent.

These weights are distributed (mostly) evenly where there isn't enough space to accommodate all the requests.  That is, if you supply two weights equal to `1`, they will be given an equal amount each (of roughly 50%) instead.

[image: Test]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class TestLayout1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout1();
    }

    public TestLayout1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel panelBtns = new JPanel();
            panelBtns.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 5));
            JButton emailBtn = new JButton("a");
            JButton saveBtn = new JButton("b");
            panelBtns.add(emailBtn);
            panelBtns.add(saveBtn);
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
//            c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            c.insets= new Insets(2,2,0,2); // panelBtns
            c.weightx = 1;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//            c.weighty = 1;
            add(panelBtns, c);

            JLabel labelTitle = new JLabel("Title");
            labelTitle.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
//            c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            c.insets=new Insets(0,5,0,5); //titleLabel
            c.weightx = 0.35;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
//            c.weighty = 1;
            add(labelTitle, c);

            JTextField textField = new JTextField();
            Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY);
            textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border,
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2)));
            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
//            c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            c.insets= new Insets(0,5,0,5); //textField
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 1;
//            c.weighty = 1;
            add(textField, c);

            JLabel bodyLabel = new JLabel("Detail");
            bodyLabel.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 3;
            c.insets=new Insets(0,5,0,5); //bodyLabel
//            c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            c.weightx = 1;
//            c.weighty = 1;
            add(bodyLabel, c);

            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
            Border border1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY);
            textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border1,
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2)));
            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 4;
//            c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            c.insets= new Insets(0, 5, 5,5); //textArea
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.weightx = 1;
            c.weighty = 1;
            add(textArea, c);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you indeed. This fixed 90% of the problems. Just one problem still remains, and if you'd like to answer, I have edited my question. Thank you again!

Comment: Try removing the `c.weighty` constraint from the `panelBtns`

Comment: Actually changing `c.weighty` of `panelBtns`, `textField` and `bodyLabel` to `0.5`; removing it from `titleLabel`, and letting that of `textArea` `10` helped get the desired result. Thank you very much!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html): _"**Generally** weights are specified with 0.0 and 1.0 as the extremes: the numbers in between are used as necessary. "_ - I think the value greater than 1 just works but is not a standard or good practice ?

Comment: @Zarah I've not looked into the code, but I suspect that it's either been normalised or reduced to it's maxium value

Comment: Because I have been thinking since the time I started learning about GridBagLayout that weighty means something like: If `a` has a `weighty` of `1` and `b` has a `weighty` of `0`, then along `y axis`, `a` is going to take `1` times more space than `b`... If that is right, the text area does not take `1` times more `vertical space` than the default `0.0` `weighty` of other components :s
However on the other hand your code works perfectly fine and produces the same result as setting a `weighty` of `10` for `textArea`.

Comment: `a` will take 100% of the **remaining** available space, the weights relate to what's left over ;) - assuming that nothing else is also wanting 100% of the space also, then it gets divided between them

Comment: Great, this is the last question on the matter: say `a` has `weighty= 1` and `b` has `weighty=0.5`, then how do you describe that?
"If the total space is divided into `3 parts`, then `1 part` is taken up by `b` and `2 parts` by `a`", is it?

Comment: I would think it might become normalized to something like `0.75` and `0.25`